# GUID Error, passing GUID from EF to DTO

Tags: c#-4.0

ERROR: 
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Guid?' to 'System.Guid'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) C:\XXX.asmx.cs

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Guid?' to 'System.Guid'.

```
 public partial class DOCUMENT
{      
    public Guid DOCUMENT_GUID { get; set; }        
}

return query.Select(x => new DOCUMENT()
            {
                //CORE DOCUMENT                   
                DOCUMENT_GUID = x.DOCUMENT_GUID,
            }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Guid?` is syntactic sugar for `Nullable<Guid>`.  It looks like you may need to say `.Value` here :

```
return query.Select(x => new DOCUMENT()
        {
            //CORE DOCUMENT                   
            DOCUMENT_GUID = x.DOCUMENT_GUID.Value,
        }).ToList();
```

Of course you could instead change the `DOCUMENT.DOCUMENT_GUID` class to have a `Nullable<Guid> DOCUMENT_GUID`.

Comment: Wish the magic sauce were that easy.. your solution compiles, but returns: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000   Also I've attempted public Nullable<global::System.Guid> DOCUMENT_GUID { get; set; }

Comment: Well good, we're half-way there.  Now we have to figure out why the code doesn't work.  Consider putting your a breakpoint on the `x =>` lambda expression and seeing what the query is really returning.  I suspect that is the problem now.

Comment: agent-j : My bad, looking at the wrong WebMethod call.  Your implementation of .Value worked!  Check+!

Comment: Great!  Happy Christmas and other holidays.

Comment: Merry Christmas to you agent-j and Happy Festivus for the Rest of Us